# Does Morgana's Black Shield activate Windspeaker's Blessing?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I use Morgana's Black Shield on an Ally, and I have Windspeaker's Blessing, will they get the Windspeaker buff?

Comment: I wonder if it procs the new Athen's as well?  I'm guessing the answer to the two questions would be the same, but not sure what that answer is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [Morgana](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Morgana)'s Black Shield is counted as a [shield](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shield), and [Windspeaker's Blessing](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Windspeaker's_Blessing_(Season_2016_Mastery)) specifically states that

> Your heals and shields are 10% stronger. Additionally, heals and shields on allies increase your target's armor by 5 - 22 (based on level) and magic resistance by 2.5 - 11 (based on level) for 3 seconds.

So, as it is a shield, it will be modified by Windspeaker's Blessing.

Comment: Thanks. I know that black shield is a different type of shield, so i didnt know if it would count.

Comment: @ShadowZ. no problem. Happy to help

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does, but that doesn't mean it is good on her. Because of the somewhat long cooldown in the early game and how easy it is to break, especially by adc's like corki and supports like sona who deal a lot of magic dmg early game, I believe thunderlord's or even DFT are way better if you play her as a support.