# WindSpeaker's blessing and all these (maybe) shields

Tags: league-of-legends

Following this question :

[Does Morgana's Black Shield activate Windspeaker's Blessing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269547/does-morganas-black-shield-activate-windspeakers-blessing)

There are many other shield type thingies that are ambiguous too.

Do the following spell/items trigger windspeaker's blessing ?

- Face of the mountain
- Galio's W bulwark
- Locket of the iron solari
- Mikael's crucible

If you have any other suggestion or shield type spell (like galio's W which is not really a shield since it doesn't absorb any damage, or items that shield/heal someone else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all those items are able to proc the effect of windspeakers blessing.

- **Face of the mountain** increases armor/mr of the ally and gains improved shield strength
- **Galios Bulwark** adds an additional amount of armor/mr and also improves the heal galio receives by 10%. Note that the heal procs this mastery too, but only the ally will gain armor/mr.
- **Locket of the Iron Solari** increases armor/mr of all allies which are affected and gains 10% improves shield strength.
- **Mikaels** heal is improved by 10% and it also grants armor/mr

**Edit 14.06.16:**
While i previously stated that Galios Bulwark does proc windspeakers blessing, this is only true for the heal. It does not grant a shield, but only armor/mr, which is not affected by windspeakers blessing as far as i know - I'll test it today when i come home and edit the result in here.